# Поиск в JSON и последующий перебор

Tags: php, json

Имеется данная JSON строка:

```
{"header":{"user_id":"27355","account_type":"1"},"results":[{"header":{"similarity":"96.45","index_id":5,"index_name":"Index #5"},"data":{"title":"\u30a8\u30f3\u5b50\u3061\u3083\u3093","id":74692665,"member_name":"\u2739\u3046\u306b\u30e2\u30f3\u2739","member_id":2173572}},{"header":{"similarity":"94.4","index_id":30,"index_name":"Index #9"},"data":{"id":3505976,"gel_id":4732753,"creator":"katuo1129","material":"original","characters":"","source":""}}]}
```

Так же имеется подобие скрипта:

```
$sau_global = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__."/json.json"));
$text = $sau_global->results[0]->header->index_name;

switch(preg_match('#\#(.*?)\:#', $text, $match)){
    case "{$match[1]}" == "25":

        echo "Gel";
        break;

    case "{$match[1]}" == "9":

        echo "Dan";
        break;

    case "{$match[1]}" == "5":

        echo "Pi";
        break;
}
```

Мне нужно что бы проверялся JSON-файл и если находит в `index_name`, например `Index #5` он выдавал результат "Pi". Но если там есть несколько `index_name` (с разными индексами соответственно) то он бы выдавал бы не только "Pi" но и "Gel" с "Dan".

**PS. Попытка №2**

```
$sau_global = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__."/json.json"));

$x = 0;
while($x <= 2){
while($result = $sau_global->results){

    switch(preg_match('#\#(.*?)\:#', $result[$x]->header->index_name, $match)){
    case $match[1] == "5":

        echo "Pixiv<br><br>";
        break;

    case $match[1] == "9":

        echo "Danbooru<br><br>";
        break;

    case $match[1] == "25":

        echo "Gelbooru<br><br>";
        break;

}

    $x++;
    break;
}}
```

Вроде все работает, но он выдает так:

> Pixiv
>
> Danbooru
>
> Pixiv

Как подправить его так что бы он не выдавал третий вариант (Pixiv) если его нет в JSON?

Comment: Ну так зачем вы проверяете только `results[0]` ?! Проверяйте все в цикле

Comment: какой однако у вас интересный `switch`. Вам не кажется, что надо сначала провериьт, вернуло ли preg_match истину, а потом уже в swaitch загнать `match[0]` и не ерунду какую то писать, гоняя булевый разультат функции по кейсам из сравнения строк ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Заранее определяем индексы
// и значения для вывода.
$indexes = [
    'Index #5' => 'Pi',
    'Index #9' => 'Dan',
    'Index #25' => 'Gel',
];

// Получаем содержимое файла.
$jsonString = file_get_contents('json.json');

// Декодируем json строку.
$sau_global = json_decode($jsonString);

// Перебираем результаты `results`.
foreach ($sau_global->results as $key => $result) {
  // Если существует поле `index_name`
  // и оно не пустое.
  if (!empty($result->header->index_name)) {
    // Выводим его значение.
    echo $indexes[$result->header->index_name], '<br><br>';
    // Пред выводом можно было бы
    // добавить различные проверки.
  }
}
```